# How to use bootstrap columns in HTML?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid

I am currently learning HTML/CSS and I stumbled upon making columns within a div, which I can't seem to figure out online. I am trying to replicate the google advanced search page (https://www.google.com/advanced_search). I would think that there are 3 columns ("Find pages with...", input field and "To do this in the search box").

However, I can't get this seem to work. I understood that Bootstrap divides the view into 12 parts, so I use a width of 2 for the first part, 6 for the second part and 4 for the last part. The output however shows everything in 1 column. This is my code below:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    All these words: <br>
                    This exact words or phrase: <br>
                    Any of these words: <br>
                    None of these words: 
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <form action = "https://google.com/search">
                        <input class = "advanced" type = "text" name = "as_q"> <br>
                        <input class = "advanced" type = "text" name = "as_epq"><br>
                        <input class = "advanced" type = "text" name = "as_oq"><br>
                        <input class = "advanced" type = "text" name = "as_eq"><br>
                        <input type = "submit" value = "Google Search">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                    <p>Type the important words: tri-colour rat terrier</p> <br>
                    <p>Put exact words in quotes: "rat terrier"</p> <br>
                    <p>Type OR between all the words you want: miniature OR standard</p> <br>
                    <p>Put a minus sign just before words that you don't want: -rodent, -"Jack Russell"</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is what I am trying to replicate:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to close your first col div : ... `<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">... 
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">` should be `<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">...</div>`then `<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">`.

Comment: Little tip, don't write HTML like setting variables. `<div class = "example">` close the gaps between class and the value. Like: `<div class="example">` this will make it easier to read your markup and to spot errors.

Comment: Also https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input can be very handy to spot mistakes within HTML.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Oh wow! Thanks for pointing that out! Appreciate it. After fixing this error, the three columns are not aligned at all. Text and input fields are vertically aligned differently. Do you happen to know what would be an easier way to fix this? I would like to replicate the image attached. Perhaps I am thinking too difficult? Would appreciate it if you could guide me in the right direction :). Thanks again!

Comment: @ArnoTenkink Great tips, thanks a lot! I will look into validator.w3!

Comment: there is 5 rows on your screenshot, you codded all inside a single row ;)